# How to enter Cisco IOS shell?

Tags: router

I feel completely stupid that I cannot figure this out.

So I have my Cisco WRT54GL router connected with ethernet cable to my Ubuntu laptop. How do I access this router's Cisco IOS shell? I literally cannot google find this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WRT54GL is a Linksys product. Linksys was bought by Cisco in March 2003, but it's currently owned by Belkin who bought it in March 2013.

Cisco IOS is only present on professional Cisco routers and switches. SOHO devices by Linksys don't have IOS. You can try telnetting to it, but don't expect IOS's advanced features.

Comment: ahhh, understood.